# How do I add 2 variables together from 2 different codes?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add the values generated from the variables "sum1" and "sum2" together, and then append that sum to the class ".results-6".

HTML

```
<p class="results-4"></p>
<p class="results-5"></p>
<p class="results-6"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    var sum1 = 0;
    var turkey = parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum1 === 1 ? sum1 : sum1++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum1 === 2 ? sum1 : sum1 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum1 === 3 ? sum1 : sum1 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum1 === 4 ? sum1 : sum1 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-4").html(sum1);
});

$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    var sum2 = 0;
    var chicken = parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum2 === 1 ? sum2 : sum2++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum2 === 2 ? sum2 : sum2 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum2 === 3 ? sum2 : sum2 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum2 === 4 ? sum2 : sum2 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-5").html(sum2);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add them together in another function when you are done:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    var sum1 = 0;
    var turkey = parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum1 === 1 ? sum1 : sum1++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum1 === 2 ? sum1 : sum1 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum1 === 3 ? sum1 : sum1 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum1 === 4 ? sum1 : sum1 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-4").html(sum1);
    addResults();
});

$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    var sum2 = 0;
    var chicken = parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum2 === 1 ? sum2 : sum2++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum2 === 2 ? sum2 : sum2 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum2 === 3 ? sum2 : sum2 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum2 === 4 ? sum2 : sum2 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-5").html(sum2);
    addResults();
});

function addResults() {
    var res4 = $(".results-4").text();
    var res5 = $(".results-5").text();
    $(".results-6").text(res4 + res5);
}
```

Or, simply combine the functions.  Plus, you could further reduce your code by eliminating duplicate calculation (assuming this isn't just an example).  I'm not sure what you are calculating, but from what I can tell, you are just returning a value depending on the range the input falls into:

```
  function calcVal(num) {
    if (num <= 5) {
      return 1;
    } else if (num <= 12) {
      return 2;
    } else if (num <= 20) {
      return 3;
    } else if (num <= 30) {
      return 4;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  $(document).on("keyup", "input", function() {
    var sum1 = calcVal(parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10));
    $(".results-4").html(sum1);

    var sum2 = calcVal(parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10));
    $(".results-5").html(sum2);

    $(".results-6").html(sum1 + sum2);
  });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help with this! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, it's in vanilla JS instead of JQuery, but it should work for you - or at the very least, the structure should help out.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    var sum1 = 0;
    var turkey = parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum1 === 1 ? sum1 : sum1++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum1 === 2 ? sum1 : sum1 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum1 === 3 ? sum1 : sum1 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum1 === 4 ? sum1 : sum1 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-4").html(sum1);
    var sum2 = 0;
    var chicken = parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10);
    if($(this).val() <= 5){ 
        sum2 === 1 ? sum2 : sum2++;
    } else if ($(this).val() >=6 && $(this).val() <=12) {
        sum2 === 2 ? sum2 : sum2 += 2;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 13 && $(this).val() <=20) {
        sum2 === 3 ? sum2 : sum2 += 3;
    } else if ($(this).val() >= 21 && $(this).val() <=30) {
        sum2 === 4 ? sum2 : sum2 += 4;
    }
    $(".results-5").html(sum2);
    //sorry this is vanilla JS, not jquery
    updateResult6();
});

function updateResult6(){
  var sum3 = document.getElementById("results-4") + document.getElementById("results-5");
  document.getElementById("results-6").innerHTML = sum3; 
}
```

```html
<p class="results-4"></p>
<p class="results-5"></p>
<p class="results-6" id="results-6"></p>
```